# Neo4j randomly shutting down

Tags: neo4j

I am running neo4j on an EC2 instance. But for some reason it randomly shuts down from time to time. Is there a way to check the shutdown logs? And is there a way to automatically restart the server? I couldn't locate the log folder. But here's what my `messages.log` file looks like. This section covers the timeframe when the server went down (before 2015-04-13 05:39:59.084+0000) and when I manually restarted the server (at 2015-**04-13** 05:39:59.084+0000). You can see that there is no record of server issue or shutdown. Time frame before 2015-**03-05** 08:18:47.084+0000 contains info of the previous server restart.

```
2015-03-05 08:18:44.180+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.m.Neo4jBrowserModule]: Mounted Neo4j Browser at [/browser]
2015-03-05 08:18:44.253+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer]: Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
2015-03-05 08:18:44.311+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer]: Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
2015-03-05 08:18:47.084+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Server started on: http://0.0.0.0:7474/
2015-03-05 08:18:47.084+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Remote interface ready and available at [http://0.0.0.0:7474/]
2015-03-05 08:18:47.084+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- SERVER STARTED END ---
2015-04-13 05:39:59.084+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-04-13 05:39:59.265+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase]: No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'community'
2015-04-13 05:39:59.383+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- INITIALIZED diagnostics START ---
2015-04-13 05:39:59.384+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Neo4j Kernel properties:
2015-04-13 05:39:59.389+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=78M
2015-04-13 05:39:59.389+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=21M
```

Comment: It should not shut down, can your share your logs in data/log/* and data/graph.db/messages.log ?

Comment: @MichaelHunger added few details

Comment: from which log is that?